# What are the differences between "conda env export -> environment.yml" and "conda list -> spec.txt"? And which is better?

Tags: anaconda, conda, dependency-management, development-environment, virtual-environment

[conda env export](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment) -> environment.yml

[conda list](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments) -> spec-file.txt (All produce raw text. File names seems to be convention)

The document is a little bit confusing. It seems that the only differences are:

- `environment.yml` has `name` and `channel` fields;
- Their respective "restoration" command: `conda env create -f environment.yml...` vs `conda create -f spec.txt...`.